# The server is taking too long to respond with the "deno run" command

Tags: powershell, server, terminal, deno

I have recently started using deno on Windows and compared to other colleagues (using MacOS), my server is taking a lot longer to respond and I get additional comments before the server gives me feedback, that it is running. I tried to manually reinstall deno and switch to various ports, but nothing worked. It would be great to receive some advice on how I could speed up this process.

```
PS C:\Users\xyz\WebProgramming\DenoBackend» deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read --unstable server.ts
Check file:///C:/Users/xyz/WebProgramming/DenoBackend/server.ts
ignoring response from [fe8@: :1%11]:53 because it does not match name_server: [fe8@: :1]:53
ignoring response from [fe8@: :1%11]:53 because it does not match name_server: [fe8@: :1]:53.
Server is running
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
By updating to Windows 11 from Windows 10 and switching to PowerShell Version 7.2.1, I don't get the "ignoring response" responses from the Terminal anymore and the server starts a lot faster.